# How to effectively use git repositories / submodules for a C++ product that has many dependencies?

Tags: c++, windows, git, version-control

I'm very new to Git and still figuring things out...  I think I'm finally understanding the whole branching/merging aspects.  But I'm still not sure what the best solution for handling project dependencies are.  What is best practice?  This has got to be a common problem and yet I can't find a good tutorial or best practice on doing this.

Suppose I have a C++ product that depends on several other C++ libraries, ultimately making up a complicated dependency graph.  Libraries like: other internally developed C++ libraries, public open source libraries, off-the-shelf closed source libraries

The final C++ product's source code relies on the output of its dependencies in order to compile.  These outputs are composed of:

- A series of C++ header files (notice that the C++ implementation files are absent)
- A set of compiled binaries (LIB files, DLL files, EXE files, etc)

My understanding is I should put each library its own repository.  Then it sounds like Git's submodules are mostly what we are looking for.  The write-up at http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/ in particular seems like a good introduction and I can *almost* understand.  For example, I could have my master project repository refer to a specific external Git repository as a submodule / dependency.  C++ code can "#include" header files in the appropriate submodule directories.  A build script included with the master product / repository could conceivably proceed to recursively compile all submodules.

OK now the question:

How do you typically cache binaries for each repository?  Some of our dependencies take hours to compile and aren't updated on a very frequent basis.  With the above scheme, I might clone / check out a high-level project from the server to fix a small bug.  Now as I understand it, I'm also forced to clone all the thousands of files that make up each of these open source dependencies - I'm worried that could take some time (especially on Windows).  Even worse, wouldn't I then be forced recompile each and every submodule, even if nobody has changed that submodule for months?  (It seems like some kind of local "hash table" scheme on each developer computer that links a changeset ID to a set of compiled binaries would be handy...)

(A previous shop I worked at a few years ago used Mercurial - the extent of , but *all* code - internal projects, etc. was rolled into one single big giant repository, and you had to build *everything* in a big fat monolithic build script when cloning a newly-created branch from the server.  When we were done with the fix / new feature and had merged back with upstream, we deleted the local repository for that particular branch.)

We're doing development on Windows, but will eventually branch out to other non-Microsoft platforms - so portability is important.

Comment: You should only have to do a full clone and build once. Just keep the clone/build files on your computer. When you need to make a quick change, just make it locally, git commit, and git push -- all your project and build files will still be there.

Comment: You can also add entries to `.gitignore` to make git ignore your build files so they won't show up in a `git status`

Comment: As I noted, in my past I had the habit of cloning the repository for a branch, working with it, then deleting the entire repository.  Sounds like I should work differently and only have one working directory?  Now with Git I can only have one branch / changeset checked out at a time... what's the best way to quickly change gears between branches?  (E.g. switch out from major new feature development to a minor bug fix branch).  Just have a collection of cloned repositories with the compiled binaries in each?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now. Personally, your last suggestion is actually exactly how I'd do it -- have multiple permanent local clones with appropriate build files in each.

Comment: There might be a better way though. I don't claim to be a git expert.

Comment: Do you need to have all of the dependencies in git? I understand you would for the internally developed libraries, and you might need it for open source libraries if you are making changes to them. Both otherwise it should be sufficient to host them elsewhere or distribute them amongst your team using binaries/installers etc. Or just put the binary/compiled libs into a vendor directory.

Comment: @Daemin:  I was thinking it would be wise for version control purposes, so that the internal projects are strongly tied to specific versions of the external libraries.  But now that you mention it, perhaps the same goal could be achieved by storing these libraries in external directories on a server, with each library in a directory identified by name.

Comment: You could do something like Rails does but store the compiled versions of the libraries in a vendor or external directory in your project's source tree. Then the source could be in the original repository, or one of your own one's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this is a bad idea, but why don't you check the binaries into the submodules as well as the compiled code for submodules that don't change often? That way, the fetch will pull down the bins, and when you compile a new version of a dependency with changed binaries, you will see the binaries show up in the git status output.

Comment: We wound up doing a slight variation of this: putting the compiled 3rd-party binaries into submodules.  Source code is kept in separate repository, so that our apps that use the binary submodules don't need to waste time cloning the source code of that project as well.  For example, "VTK-bin" is the submodule used by our product, and "VTK-source" contains source code used to generate "VTK-bin".